# Iterate over array-field in the html-template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a collection of bookmark:

```
> db.Bookmarks.find()
{ "Name" : "Lenta.ru", "Timestamp" : 1381233418275, "URL" : "http://lenta.ru", "_id" : "zS2ccZXkGLENzN2Bx", "tags" : [  "asdx" ] }
{ "Name" : "Another", "Timestamp" : 1381234763188, "URL" : "http://ya.ru", "_id" : "qAB46c38hEFSw3NTE", "tags" : [  "one",  "two" ] }
```

The field 'tags' has type of array.

I have a HTML template to iterate over bookmarks:

```
<template name="bookmarks">
    {{#each bookmarks}}
          <a href="{{URL}}" class="bookmark_url">{{Name}}</a>
          <div> {{tags}} </div>
        {{/each}}
</template>
```

I want to display each tag into a separate 'div'.  Something like this:

```
<template name="bookmarks">
    {{#each bookmarks}}
          <a href="{{URL}}" class="bookmark_url">{{Name}}</a>
          {{#each tags}}
             <div> {{current_tag}} </div>
          {{/each}}
        {{/each}}
</template>
```

How can I do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of {{current_tag}}, does {{this}} work? Also it would be best to have each tag instead be an object with an _id (even if you generate it) -- Spark likes that

Comment: Yes, {{this}} works fine.  Thanks. Can you please create answer and I will accept it? And can you please explain this: 'Also it would be best to have each tag instead be an object with an _id (even if you generate it)' ? I didn't understand it.

Comment: I'll post the answer shortly. As for _id, it's better explained here: http://fogofcode.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/on-the-importance-of-_id-when-iterating-with-each-in-handlebarsmeteor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over a simple array, use `{{this}}` to access the value of each iteration.

```
{{#each tags}}
  <div>{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

I recommend converting your `tags` array into an array of objects, such as:

```
"tags": [{_id: "1", "somevalue"}, {_id: "2", "someothervalue"}]
```

The Spark rendering engine is better able to decide when to redraw the content of an `#each` when unique IDs are involved. Reference: http://fogofcode.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/on-the-importance-of-_id-when-iterating-with-each-in-handlebarsmeteor/

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#each current_tag in tags}}
    <div> {{current_tag}} </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I can look all elements outside this {{#each}} block, but nothing inside it (even if I put static text inside it).